# How to create PODO class based on dynamically changing keys in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, dart

I have json object with list of elements, the last element includes a string that contains each key separated by comma.

```
  [
    {"US":1M, "UK":2M,"Swiss":3M,"Spain":0.5M,"Germany":10M},
    {"US":1.5M, "UK":26M,"Swiss":31M,"Spain":0.56M,"Germany":1M},

    {"total":10000,"key":"US,UK,Swiss,Spain,Germany"}
  ]
```

Key field in last element will be changed and based on that string rest of the list will be generated. if the key has 10 strings separated by comma, then each list will contains 10 items. How can I generate a PODO class by adding a loop based on the number of the strings?